# Python Flask SelectField selection gets DB row and populates the web page Textboxes with DB row entry

Tags: python, jquery, sqlite, flask, wtforms

I am trying to create a Python/Flask web app and currently i am stuck on one thing.  on the Assign Handset page i want to have a drop down box which displays a bunch of user ID from a sqlite database call, and every time a selection is made the other fields on the page get populated with the corresponding data from the database row.

I have found some tutorials, well, a lot of tutorials which discuss AJAX and PHP, but none for Python/Flask that fit my needs.

Here is a screenshot of the web page to give you an idea:
[image: Assign Handset]

I have been reading about JQuery, but, i got to say, it is way above my head and i am struggling with it. I only recently found out that you cannot run some java script straight from the browser because of security risks and that you need a HTTP server (python -m http.server in my case :-)).

As you can see from the picture, when someone clicks the soon to be 'TATA SAP Number' drop down box, the selection will get the relating database record and populate the relating fields with the database row details.  I want to be able to do this without having to load the page each time, if possible!

if someone can point me to a *working* Python/Flask, maybe JQuery tutorial on how to do this i will be very grateful!!!  or point me in the direction of some tutorials which will help me build up to doing this myself...

Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes you need a minimum knowledge of JQuery (more precisely in ajax) to make requests without updating the page. The good news is that Flask's own documentation has ready examples.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/

Comment: Thank you for your response Vinicius, that particular page was very helpful with running JS pages.  Do you know for any online ajax/JQuery tutorials which cover this area? Which is JQuery/Ajax on the python/flask framework ?